# How can I set a fake microphone on PhantomJS?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I need to simulate audio input using Selenium with PhantomJS. I already know I can do it by using chromedriver:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("use-fake-device-for-media-stream");
options.addArguments("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");
```

Is it possible to do it using PhantomJS?

Comment: Not supported. It's a headless driver. They don't support visuals or audio. Since it would require a bunch of codecs.